# OnClick from other function - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if there is a way to get the onclick function of a div and execute it when the backKey is pressed, thanks :)

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==48) {
    alert("You hit the enter key.");
 try{
  getOnClick();
 }catch(err){alert("Can't go back");}
  } else {
  }
}

function getOnClick()
{
 var obj = document.getElementById('btn');
 //i need to execute obj.onClick();
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn" onClick="alert('click');">BTN</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `obj.click()` dispatches an event that should trigger the handler.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the click event to your button , also your syntax is incorrect on the button element . It should be **onclick** all lowercase instead of **onClick**

remove onclick attribute from element and try this :

```
function getOnClick()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('btn');
    obj.onclick = keyDownTextField
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

function keyDownTextField(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==48) {
    alert("You hit the enter key.");
    try{
        getOnClick();
    }catch(err){alert("Can't go back");}
  } else {
  }
}

function getOnClick()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById('btn');

     // This is all you need to do
     obj.click();

    //i need to execute obj.onClick();
}
```

obj.click(); trigger and solve everything for you